# Присвоить цвет из своего файла по ключу

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, resources

У меня есть файл стилей, который называется **Styles.xaml** и который содержит следующие строки:

```xml
<Color x:Key="StackLayoutBackColor">#e3e6ef</Color>
<Color x:Key="ErrorColor">#dc4e41</Color>
<Color x:Key="Green">#36b649</Color>
<Color x:Key="TextColor">#ffffff</Color>
```

Далее в юзер контроле я делаю валидацию ошибок и хочу присвоить цвет контура контролу:

```cs
var control = (UsernameEntry) bindable;
control.Frame.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
```

Код выше работает прекрасно, но мне надо присвоить именно мой цвет из файла стилей. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `control.Frame.BackgroundColor = (Color)this.FindResource("StackLayoutBackColor");` наверное как-то так, я плохо знаю Xamarin. Но смысл в том, что вам нужно искать ресурс по его текстовому названию. Коррекстность работы зависит от того, где у вас именно эти цвета, в Page или еще где-то подключены. А может вот так еще можно `= (Color)Application.Current.Resources ["StackLayoutBackColor"]`

Comment: Увы, оба случая не работают. Во втором ловлю NotImplementedException

Comment: Ну так вы не сказали, куда там этот ResourceDictionary подключается. Название xaml файла может быть любое. Весь смысл в том, что вы вообще его подключили к проекту или нет. И если да, то куда.

Comment: <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary>

Это в xaml контрола

Comment: Попробуйте это в xaml страницы вставить, в C# коде которой вы пытаетесь выполнить `FindResource`.

Comment: Этот код и так находится в xaml страницы. Cannot resolve symbol 'FindResource'

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49211/accessing-resourcedictionary-from-xaml-to-c-programmatically